# How to get name of file in source csh

Tags: shell, csh

I know `perl` has `$0` to name the file. Is there a variable when you source a file in `csh` that is the name of the file being sourced?

Answer (score 1):

`$0` Also works in `csh`, consider this example

```csh
#!/bin/csh -f

echo "--> $0"
```

Output: --> /tmp/test.csh

---

[csh(1) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/csh):

> **$0**
> Substitutes the name of the file from which command input is being read. An error occurs if the name is not known.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
#!/bin/csh

echo $0
```

Comment: Thanks @kometen I was thinking of maybe executing to a csh to solve the problem. Thanks